# Sending Parameters to Common JS file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Im wondering if it is possible to minimize my code by having a common JS file, As there will be many datatables around my application..

All the Datatables will have same theme only difference will be of data.

Like this script i have

```
    var oTable =  $('#ManageForms').dataTable({
         "aoColumns": [
             /* ID */   {
                 "bVisible":    false,
                 "bSortable":   false,
                 "bSearchable": false
             },
             /* Form Name */  null,
             /* Form Path */  null,
             /* Form CI Path */  null,
             /* Actions */  null
         ],

        "bServerSide":true,
        "bProcessing":true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        //"bFilter":true,
        //"sServerMethod": "POST",
        "sAjaxSource": "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/listForms_DT/",
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "aLengthMenu": [[2, 25, 50, -1], [2, 25, 50, "All"]],
        /*"sEcho": 1,
        "columns":[
            {data:"FormName"},
            {data:"FormPath"},
            {data:"FormCIPath"},
            { "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<a href='#editBtnModal' class='editBtnFunc' ><i style='color: #666666' class='fa fa-pencil fa-fw fa-2x'></i></a><a href='#' id='deleteBtn'><i style='color: #ff0000' class='fa fa-times fa-fw fa-2x'></i></a>",
                "targets": -1
            }
        ],*/
        'fnServerData'   : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
            $.ajax ({
                'dataType': 'json',
                'type'    : 'POST',
                'url'     : sSource,
                'data'    : aoData,
                'success' : fnCallback
            }); //end of ajax
        },
        'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
            $(nRow).attr("data-id",aData[0]);
            return nRow;
        }
    });
```

i guess everything will be same except the `sAjaxSource": "{{base_url()}}admin/configurations/listForms_DT/",`
and

```
         "aoColumns": [
             /* ID */   {
                 "bVisible":    false,
                 "bSortable":   false,
                 "bSearchable": false
             },
             /* Form Name */  null,
             /* Form Path */  null,
             /* Form CI Path */  null,
             /* Actions */  null
         ],
```

so instead of copy pasting the code again and again on every page of datatables. is there any way i put this code in single common.js file and send the parameters for specific datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your code in a function which could be call in each specific case with the url needed as param:

```
function getData(url){
   // ...
  "sAjaxSource": url
  // ...
}
```

this function can be in a common js and then use in any other code that is after you import this file.

The array in aoColumns can also be passed as param as the other field.